# Problem when saving an array of scriptable objects into a json file UNITY/C#

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, serialization, save

Im trying to store the data of an array of scriptable objects into a serialized json files, when I only save 1 object there is no problem, but when I try to loop and save all the array it only saves me the last one in the array. Any idea of how can I solve this?

C# code-

```
 public static GameSaveManager instance;

[SerializeField] private ShopItem[] shopitems;
[SerializeField] private BackgroundShopItem[] backgroundShopItems;

private void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    else if (instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(this);
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}

public bool IsSaveFile()
{
    return Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "game_save");
}

public void SaveGame()
{
    if (!IsSaveFile())
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_save");
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_sava/data"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_save/data");
    }

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

    for (int i = 0; i < shopitems.Length; i++)
    {
        ShopItem si = shopitems[i];

        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_save/data/skins_save.txt");
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(si);
        bf.Serialize(file, json);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify on how you're adding items to `ShopItem[]` maybe by pasting code?

Comment: @HurpaDerpa ShopItem[] is the scriptable object, I just fill the array dragging in the inspector

Comment: You seem to close the file in the loop... you want to close it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop `for (int i = 0; i < shopitems.Length; i++)` you save every file to the *same* location - `Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_save/data/skins_save.txt"`, so you get your file overrided. Just use different save files: `Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_save/data/skins_save_{i}.txt"`

If you want to serialize it to one file, consider implementing your own Serializable class for it and keep your ShopItem[] array there.

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveItems
{
    public ShopItem[] shopitems;
}
```

So in your SaveGame() you'll get something like this:

```
public void SaveGame()
{
    // previous code here

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

    SaveItems si = new SaveItems();
    si.shopitems = shopitems;    

    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_save/data/skins_save.txt");
    var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(si);
    bf.Serialize(file, json);
    file.Close();

}
```

Comment: I just tried what you said but the "{i}" is detected as a string and is just applied to file name. I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I edited the post, reload to see it. Yes {i} is applied to file name, but actually I assume that you want to get only one file instead of bunch of files.

Comment: Im pretty new on this so let me ask, is it better having a saved file for each shopItem or just one file containing all the saved data as you mentioned on your edited reply?

Comment: I think that keeping all the data in one place is a reasonable idea because your data seems to be simple enough and pretends to be loaded all at ones. If you want to save a bloated classes or implement loading of separate shopItems then you should look into saving each shopItem separately. But it's only my opinion, I'm not too experienced enough to consider my opinion right without any clues.

Comment: Thanks for your response! And, how could it be done to store the data in different files as mentioned before? So I know both ways of doing it :D

Comment: Emm, just use {i} suffix or any other file naming that you'd like. By the way, don't forget to mark question as accepted so no one else will misunderstood it for question that needs help.